# why cannot find the directory /election in zookeeper about "Leader Election"

Tags: apache-zookeeper

in zookeeper documentation, its said, when "Leader Election" happen,each znode creates a child znode "/election/n_" .
why i cannot see the directory "/election" in zookeeper.

[zookeeper documentation about Leader Election screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uy5Wy.png)

[zookeeper root directory screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uy5Wy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning of this "Leader Election" is that your application use ZK to do yourself leader election. It is not the ZK do itself leader election. They are quite two different things.